# How do I change DataFilter based on a user permission?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Where would be the best place to be able to enable/disable a filter for the entire session of the user, conditionally based on a permission?

For example I have a "CanSeeDeletedItems" permission, only for admins, and I want to apply that to everything, Ie, disable the SoftDelete filter when a request comes from a user with this permission.

I first thought to try and include this in modelBuilder, but quickly realized I cannot access the Service layer from the DAL.

So my thoughts would be to add some code to the Initializer of UOW somehow, but I am not sure how to do this, I was hoping it was a case already considered but not written into the documentation.

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
if (IsGranted("PermissionName")) 
CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete);`
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example? and let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: Not really, because it is more of an architectural question than a specific code question. But I'll add some details.... if it helps.

Comment: You can use `[AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.PermissionName)]` on top of your appservice method

Comment: I updated the question @viveknuna

Comment: please check my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

For user based disabling filter can be achieved with Interceptors.
So what you need to do is; Write a custom interceptor for Application Services.

This interceptor must disable/enable filter for the current execution

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-using-Interceptors/index.html#ArticleCreateInterceptor

---

**To disable AspNet Boilerplate filter using in code block**

```
using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete))
{
    var people2 = _personRepository.GetAllList();                
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#disable-filters

---

**To disable AspNet Boilerplate filter globally**

```
Configuration.UnitOfWork.OverrideFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete, false);
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#disable-filters-globally

Comment: I need to use it globally, not just in a method

Comment: by the way @Worthy7 you have asked the same question 1 year ago :) https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1752

Comment: Lol no, it's a different but similar question. This is about using Permission to dictate if a filter is enabled or not :D

Comment: And actually, what you mean is this: `CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete)`